# How to deny HTTP methods (or verbs) for path in ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config, http-method

For security reasons i want to disable some http methods(e.x. OPTIONS,TRACE,HEAD) through application level. I want to do this for all files in directory "bundles/"

But this path is actually created by this

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/Something").Include("~/Contents/Scripts/file.js"));
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/Anything").Include("~/Areas/Import/Scripts/App/anotherfile.js"));
```

Fow now I tried this (in Web.config)

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="bundles/" verb="OPTIONS,TRACE,HEAD" type="System.Web.HttpMethodNotAllowedHandler" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

but it doesn't work

So, I want user gets **405 Method Not Allowed** when making OPTIONS, TRACE, HEAD requests for any link like **myapp.com/bundles/example**

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this like that:

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />
        <deny verbs="TRACE" users="*" />
        <deny verbs="HEAD" users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

...

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="bundles" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
        <add path="bundles" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
        <add path="bundles" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

Comment: It works but for all app pages, but I need to deny methods only for this link "example.com/bundles"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<add path="bundles" verb="OPTIONS" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
<add path="bundles" verb="TRACE" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
<add path="bundles" verb="HEAD" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler" validate="true"/>
```